# List job's pending steps

Tags: slurm

The scenario is this one, I allocate ressources (2 nodes, 64 CPUs) to job with salloc:

```
salloc -N 1-2 -n 64 -c 1 -w cluster-node[2-3] -m cyclic -t 5
salloc: Granted job allocation 1720
```

Then, I use `srun` to create steps to my job:

```
for i in (seq 70)
    srun --exclusive -N 1 -n 1 --jobid=1720 sleep 60 &
end
```

Because I created more steps than available cpus for my job, steps are "pending" until a free CPU.

When I use `squeue` with -s option to list steps, I'm only able to view the running ones.

```
squeue -s -O stepid:12,stepname:10,stepstate:9
1720.0     sleep     RUNNING
[...]
1720.63     sleep     RUNNING
```

My question is, does steps have status different from *RUNNING* like jobs, and if yes, is there a way to view those with squeue (or other command) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure Slurm can offer the information. One alternative would be to use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) so that jobs steps are not started at all until a CPU is available. In the current setting all job steps are started at once and those which do not have a CPU available are waiting.

So with the same allocation as you use, replace

```
for i in (seq 70)
    srun --exclusive -N 1 -n 1 --jobid=1720 sleep 60 &
end
```

with

```
parallel -P $SLURM_NTASKS srun --exclusive -N 1 -n 1 --jobid=1720 sleep 60
```

Then the output of squeue should list RUNNING and PENDING steps.

N.B. not sure the `--jobid=` option is needed here BTW

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my real objective was to find a way to use cyclic distribution of task for balancing the workload on nodes. After a deep dive in the manual, I finally found the LLD option in the configuration which works great. Thanks for the parallel tip, I'm a big fan of this command !